# Which masthead editor to address a cover letter to for a short fiction submission?

Tags: submitting-work, cover-letter

Most advice says to include the editor's name in the cover letter. In researching mastheads, however, I find: Executive Editor, Managing editor, Regional Editors, Senior Editors, etc. (of course if I find a "Fiction Editor" or "Literary Editor" that's easy, but many don't).

Which editor should I use and if I can't find one, or can't choose, what's the proper way to address the magazine in general? "Dear New Yorker" or "Dear Fiction Editor"?

Comment: Do you know which editor will actually be responsible for reviewing your submission? They might spell it out somewhere. If not, I suppose the catch-all "To whom it may concern" can work, but it's a bit stilted IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are addressing a specific publisher, you probably have some idea of the kinds of books they put out. The quick and dirty way to find the person to address your submission to is to find a book they have recently published which is similar to yours, and to find out who edited it. Editors often get acknowledged by authors, so this should not be difficult. Then, make sure they still work there, first.

They may not be the person to ultimately review your submission, but they will likely be the person you will be working with.

The more intensive and recommended way to do it is to go to conventions to meet some editors to learn who they are and what they like. After that, all the preceding applies.